# Erro ao incluir o somatorio de valores no rodapé de uma gridview

Tags: c#, sql-select, entity-framework-6, datagridview

Estou tentando incluir no rodapé de uma `gridview` o somatório de duas colunas, mas estou com dificuldades em criar o método que realiza esta função.

Já pus a propriedade `ShowFooter` como `true`, agora tenho que implementar o evento `DataBound` mas não esta funcionando. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
 protected void gvcarteira_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    double val1 = 0;
        double val2 = 0;
       // foreach (GridViewRow row in gvcarteira.Rows)

        for (int i; gvcarteira.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // converte o preco e a qtde para multiplicar e somar no total         

            double qt = double.Parse(gvcarteira.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
            double qtd = double.Parse(gvcarteira.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);


            val1 = val1 + qt;
            val2 = val2 + qtd;


        }
        gvcarteira.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = "Valor das Ações";
        gvcarteira.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = val1.ToString();

        gvcarteira.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = "Valor Gasto";
        gvcarteira.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = val2.ToString();
      }
```

Quero que fique mais ou  menos assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A maneira de definir valores está correta. O que exatamente está acontecendo com a `GridView`?

Comment: (gvcarteira.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text), como nesse caso não foi declarado o i da erro, mas se deixo vaio da erro.

Comment: O erro, então, acontece aqui: `double qt = double.Parse(gvcarteira.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);`

Comment: É um dos casos dependendo do tipo de laço que eu implemente, se for o foreach o erro esta no i que não foi delclarado. se uso o for o erro da no gvcarteira.Rows.Count - 1 .

Comment: Mas ele foi declarado. Vou colocar uma resposta pra você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exemplo:**

***GridView:***

```cs
<asp:GridView ID="GridDados" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" ItemType="WebAppDiegoWebForms.Fulano" OnRowDataBound="GridDados_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Codigo" HeaderText="Código" DataFormatString="{0:0000}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Data" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantidade" HeaderText="Quantidade" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Valor" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" HeaderText="Valor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ValorParcial" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" HeaderText="Valor Parcial" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Na sua ***GridDados*** tem a colunas **Quantidade**, **Valor** e **ValorParcial** e no `Footer` será somando todos os valores de **ValorParcial**.

Como:

***Modelo de classe:***

```cs
public class Fulano
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public Decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

***Código dessa WebForm***

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var valores = (new Fulano[] 
        {
            new Fulano { Codigo = 1,  Nome = "Fulano 1", Data = DateTime.Now, Valor = 100M, Quantidade = 2},
            new Fulano { Codigo = 2, Nome = "Fulano 2", Data = DateTime.Now, Valor = 200M, Quantidade = 1},
            new Fulano { Codigo = 3, Nome = "Fulano 3", Data = DateTime.Now, Valor = 100M, Quantidade = 1},
            new Fulano { Codigo = 4, Nome = "Fulano 4", Data = DateTime.Now, Valor = 150M, Quantidade = 1},
            new Fulano { Codigo = 5, Nome = "Fulano 5", Data = DateTime.Now, Valor = 300M, Quantidade = 1}
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Codigo,
            x.Nome,
            x.Data,
            x.Valor,
            x.Quantidade,
            ValorParcial = (x.Valor * x.Quantidade)
        })
        .ToArray();

        GridDados.DataSource = valores;
        GridDados.DataBind();
    }
}

private decimal total = 0;
private decimal valor = 0;        
protected void GridDados_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        valor = 0;               
        if (decimal.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[5].Text, out valor)){
            total += valor;
        }

    } else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Total:";
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = total.ToString("N2");
        total = 0;
    }            
}
```

O carregamento nesse exemplo é manual, mas, pode utilizar da sua maneira. A única pecularidade que antes de enviar para o `GridView` **GridDados** eu faço uma multiplicação `ValorParcial = (x.Valor * x.Quantidade)` e envio os dados para grid todos formatados.

No `GridDados_RowDataBound` eu faço as devidas operações de soma e no final mostro no Footer do GridView. Obs: as variáveis do tipo `decimal` ***total*** e ***valor*** são colocadas fora do método `GridDados_RowDataBound`.

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O problema não é o *footer* em si. É a iteração do laço. Considere trocar o `for` por um `foreach`, que é mais seguro:

```
foreach (GridViewRow linha in gvcarteira.Rows)
{
    // converte o preco e a qtde para multiplicar e somar no total         

    double qt = double.Parse(linha.Cells[3].Text);
    double qtd = double.Parse(linha.Cells[4].Text);

    val1 = val1 + qt;
    val2 = val2 + qtd;

}
```

Comment: O visual studio não esta reconhecendo Cells, esta me dando o erro abaixo: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, sim. Perdão. Editei. Veja agora.

Comment: tenho que adicionar algum  using?

Comment: `using System.Data`, se não houver.

Comment: Com esse using ele não reconhece o Cells, sem ele o vs não reconhece o DataRow. não seria row.Cells?

Comment: Certo. Modifiquei novamente.

Comment: ok agora aparece um erro de compilação: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. não seria pelo fato de eu passar os dado por referencia para o gridview?

Comment: Não sei. Só conferindo por breakpoint agora.

Comment: só mais uma duvida esse código vai em qual evento ? no DataBound ou RowDataBound?

Comment: O ideal seria ir no `RowDataBound`, e você ir definindo o total a cada linha.

Comment: O total de cada linha eu já tenho estou tentando definir o total geral de uma coluna especifica.

Comment: Não, não. Eu disse, o total **a cada** linha, não **de cada** linha.